# CSS keyframe animation using current background colour

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I want to animate the background colour of the body tag from its current colour to a specified colour.

```
@-webkit-keyframes aboutColour /*--for webkit--*/{
    0%   {background-color: X;}
    100% {background-color: red;}
}
```

So X above would be whatever it currently is. The background colour equivalent of CSS currentColor would be ideal (the background colour is already animating and the animation above is trigger by another event).

I have JQuery included in my project if that helps.

Cheers. 
Thomas.

Comment: Why not set red as `rgb(255, 0, 0)` and then just set all other colurs using rgb as well?

Comment: The background colour is already animating so don't want to set the first colour, just use whatever is currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to use two layers, first whith background-color X and second with the animation, but using also opacity:

HTML:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="foo"></div> // Animate this div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg { position:relative; background-color: X }
.foo { width:100%; height:100%; -webkit-animation: aboutColor [...] ;} 

@-webkit-keyframes aboutColour /*--for webkit--*/{
    0%   {background-color: transparent; opacity: 0}
    100% {background-color: red; opacity: 1}
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. My only concern is diluting the colours but I can't imagine if your solution would do that or not, guess there's only one way to find out...

Comment: the problem is that you cant use "current color" in CSS, you have to define always initial and finish state in animations :(

I've thinking a bit more, and maybe a inner shadow could do the trick, but i cant test right now. It would be something like...

@-webkit-keyframes aboutColour {
    0%   { box-shadow: none}
    100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 999px red inset }
}

Comment: You can use currentcolor as I tried it, the issue is that it gives you the color and not the background-color. I ended up using the JQuery color as I'm doing a lot with colour and interactivity. But I think your first solution is probably the best CSS only solution in answer to the question so will up mark that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1951962 thanks! I'm glad that you got it working, javascript is always a solution to go ;)